# How to change the default color on MahApps Metro slider

Tags: wpf, slider, mahapps.metro

```
<Slider x:Name="CustomSliderVertical" 
        Height="10" 
        Width="150"
        Margin="0,10"
        Maximum="50"
        SmallChange="0.1"
        LargeChange="5"
        TickPlacement="None"
        TickFrequency="10" 
        Value="5"
        Style="{DynamicResource FlatSlider}"
        ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Value}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center">
</Slider>
```

[image]

So i want to do some style.
How to change colors of this `Slider` (`thump` black color)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `BorderBrush` property of the `Slider` to some other `Brush` than `Black`:

```
<Slider x:Name="CustomSliderVertical" 
        Height="10" 
        Width="150"
        Margin="0,10"
        Maximum="50"
        SmallChange="0.1"
        LargeChange="5"
        TickPlacement="None"
        TickFrequency="10" 
        Value="5"
        Style="{DynamicResource FlatSlider}"
        ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Value}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        BorderBrush="Red">
</Slider>
```

Comment: @falukky: Did you try this? Please remember to accept the answer and vote it up of your issue has been solved.